# Passing handles/hObject when the enter key is pressed to stop mouse motion :Matlab

Tags: matlab-guide

Consider the following code:

```
set(gcf,'windowbuttonmotionfcn',@wbmfcn,'KeyPressFcn',@kp);
function kp(varargin,hObject,eventdata)
fig = varargin{1};
c = get(fig,'CurrentCharacter')

% 13 is the ascii value for a carriage return
if (c == 13)
     set(fig,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','');
     set(handles.SelectRegion,'Enable','inactive');
     set(handles.Preview,'Enable','on');
     set(handles.SelectRegion,'Enable','off');
     set(handles.Capture,'Enable','on') ;
end
```

The function checks what key is pressed and if an enter key is pressed the mouse stops moving. When the enter key is pressed, certain pushbuttons are enable and certain ones are disable. How does one pass hObject and eventdata while using varagin?

Comment: You need to reorder the input variable definition so `varargin` is after any required inputs.

Comment: I reordered it as such `function kp(hObject,eventdata,varargin)` however I get an error Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ImageRegionSelect>kp (line 54)
fig = varargin{1};
 
Error while evaluating Figure KeyPressFcn

Comment: You're not passing anything to `kp` so `varargin` is going to be empty.